# Inequality for Sums of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

- Let $X_1\ldots X_n$ be independent, and let $S_k:=\sum_{i\leq k}X_i$.
- The task is to prove that $\mathbb{P}[|S_n|>a]\geq \mathbb{P}[\max_{k\leq n}|S_k|\geq2a] \min_{k\leq n}\mathbb{P}[|S_n-S_k|\leq a]$.

I know that we need to use the fact that $S_n-S_k$ and $S_k$ are independent, but can anyone show me how to actually get started ?.

Comment: Your statement is a little confusing.  Is min inside or outside the probability?  Are you multiplying probabilities?

Comment: The min is inside and yes they are multiplied

Comment: Just to be clear the last part of the expression should be $P[min_{k\le n}|S_n-S_k|\le a]$?  If so, you should correct.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake! The min is outside, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so-called *Ottaviani's inequality*. Let $A_k:=\{\max_{1\le i\le k-1}|S_i|\le 2a,|S_k|>2a\}$. Then

\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(|S_n|>a)&=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathsf{P}(|S_n|>a,A_k)+\mathsf{P}(|S_n|>a,A_n^c) \\
&\ge \sum_{k=1}^n \mathsf{P}(|S_n|>a,A_k)\ge \sum_{k=1}^n \mathsf{P}(|S_n-S_k|\le a,A_k) \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathsf{P}(|S_n-S_k|\le a)\mathsf{P}(A_k) \\
&\ge \min_{1\le k\le n} \mathsf{P}(|S_n-S_k|\le a)\times \mathsf{P}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right) \\
&=\min_{1\le k\le n} \mathsf{P}(|S_n-S_k|\le a)\times \mathsf{P}\left(\max_{1\le k\le n}|S_k|>2a\right).
\end{align}